# How to solve this derivative problem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

First time I see a problem like this, that does not give me direct data (or that I don't see).
Would you be so kind to tell me how to solve this graphical problem with derivatives?
The mechanics of derivation is no problem for me, but this problem left me speechless, although I think it should be very easy. I thought about taking the straight part of the interval between the y-axis and x=2 , but I do not see an exact value to calculate an equation of the straight line and then derive it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a straight line in that neighborhood

Comment: As @HariShankar says but be careful with the scale.

Comment: Positive, about $2.5$, horizontal, ... all seems applicable to fill out as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to approximate. The derivative of a function is sometimes thought of as "local slope"; that is, near the point you are concerned with, the function is roughly linear.

$(1,13)$ and $(3,17)$ appear to be two points on either side of $x=2$. The slope between these points is $2$ and so that is a (rough) estimate on what the derivative of your function is at the point $x=2$.

Comment: I'ld rather choose $(2,15)$ and $(4,20)$ ...

Comment: Sounds good too.

Comment: $x=1$ is not on the linear part of the graph; and for $x=3$ you have to estimate $y$ whereas for  $x=2$ and $x=4$, you are on the linear part *and* you get nice intersections with the grid  so you can read off the $y$ values more easily (admittedly,  the thick lines of the drawing make it more difficult than it should be in this case). That's why @MichaelHoppe's choice of points it better.

Comment: Sure. Ultimately, it is a blurry graph and if a student gave me either approximation I would see it as reasonable.

Comment: hello, does anyone else have another opinion